# Improving time efficiency of code, working with a big Data Set using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I’m trying to optimize my code to reduce the time it takes to run through the data set.

I’m working with a .csv file that has three columns: **time_UTC**, **vmag2D** and **vdir**. The data set as around 1420000 lines (one million, four hundred and 20 thousand).

This for cycle took around 15/20 minutes to run on my Mac with the M1 processor. I’m sure I complicated something for it to take so much time. (I believe the processor is good enough to run this little piece of code faster).

```
import pandas as pd

path_data = '" *insert a path here* "'
file = path_data + ' *name of the .csv file* '

data = pd.read_csv(file)

time_UTC = []
vmag2D = []
vdir = []

for i in range(len(data)):
    x = data.iloc[i][0]
    x1 = x.split(' ')
    x2 = x1[1].split(';')
    date = x.split(' ')[0]
    time_UTC.append(x2[0])
    vmag2D.append(x2[1])
    vdir.append(x2[2])
```

The code is parsing each of the lines in the .csv file, and each of them has the same “template”: **'1994-01-01 00:05:00;0.52;193'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be necessary to use any type of for loop for your code. You are reading the CSV using pandas, but you don't seem to specify the correct parameters.

```
import pandas as pd

path_data = '" *insert a path here* "'
file = path_data + ' *name of the .csv file* '

df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=';', parse_dates=[0], engine='c', header=None)

time_UTC = df.iloc[:, 0]
vmag2D = df.iloc[:, 1]
vdir = df.iloc[:, 2]
```

If you run this, your resulting variables (`time_UTC`, ...) will be of type `pandas.Series`. You can convert those to `list` with `.to_list()` or access the numpy array using `.values`.

Note that I am specifying `engine='c'` here in the pandas CSV parser, which is using a native C parser that is faster than its python equivalent, as you are processing a large file here.

Comment: Worked perfectly! exactly what I was looking for! the run time before was 29minutes and now it is instantaneous! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can split the entire column at once

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"all": ["1994-01-01 00:05:00;0.52;193"]*1000})

# split at space " "
df[["date", "time vmag vdir"]] = df["all"].str.split(" ", expand=True)

# split at ";"
df[["time", "vmag2D", "vdir"]] = df['time vmag vdir'].str.split(';', expand=True)

date = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]).to_list()
time_UTC = pd.to_datetime(df["time"]).to_list()
vmag2D = pd.to_numeric(df["vmag2D"]).to_list()
vdir = pd.to_numeric(df["vdir"]).to_list()
```